# List of possibilities of selecting 3 different elements 40 times with limited pools

Tags: python, combinatorics

I want to print the combinations of thes following events.

I have 13 X's, 14 Y's and 13 Z's.

I want to save all possible combinations so picking an X, Y, Z 4 40 times until emptied.

A solution could of course just be `[13 X's, 14 Y's, 13 Z's]`, `[Z, 13 X's, 14 Y's, 12 Z's]` etc..

My intuitions tells you 40 times should pick between 3 events giving 120 combinations but I could be horribly wrong.

Now I would like to visualize all combinations in a python list.

Edit: There must be way many more combinations.

For a simpler example could be three lists with [1,1,1], [2,2,2,2], [3,3,3]

And for output it should be list of

[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3],[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,2],[1,1,1,2,2,3,2,2,3,3]

And so on...

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: You question is pretty unclear, some input and expected output would help

Answer (score 2):

There are `(40 choose 13) * (27 choose 14) == 241365994493904000` possible combinations. You can pick 13 of 40 positions for the X's, then 14 of 27 remaining positions for the Y's, and then the Z's go in the positions left.

Abandon this task and try to find some other way to achieve your underlying goal.